# Django Many to Many Relationship backward querying

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models named 'Author' and 'Entry' as defined below.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    msgtoauthor = models.TextField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I am trying to access 'Author.msgtoauthor' from 'Entry'.

I know, I can retrieve the relationship between Entry and Author by

```
e = Entry.objects.get(authors)
```

Is it possible to extract the author id?

I know in the backend, Django creates a table for Authors and Entries but I want to update 'msgtoauthors' from a method in 'Entry'.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean

```
for author in my_entry.authors.all():
    author.msgtoauth = 'Here is new content'
    author.save()
```

?

`Entry.authors` returns a `RelatedManager` and `my_entry.authors.all()` is a QuerySet, that returns the Author objects. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships.

(Updated.)

Comment: I have a function within class Entry 
`def msgtoat(self):
    #update msgtoauthor`
So I want to update that variable using the above function for every author for a particular entry. I can't change the class of this function.

Comment: Yeah, sort of. Before I do that I need to query the Authors for id right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

    def msgtoat(self, message):
        self.authors.update(msgtoauthor=message)
```

For example, to update an entry:

```
entry.msgtoat('Hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the authors get the same value you can do:

```
entry.authors.update(msgtoauthor='Hey there!')
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Ry10p/django-Plugis/blob/master/courses/models.py
line 52

```
class name():
    the_thing1 = models.CharField()
    another = models.TextField()


class name2():
    the_thing2 = models.ForignKey(the_thing1)
    another2 = models.ForignKey(another)
```

-Cheers